# How to call two functions alternately on clicking an element?

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li class='selectable'>Data</li>
   <li class='deselectable'>Data</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(".selectable").click(function()
{
    alert("select "+$(this).prop("class"));
    //data
    $(this).removeClass('selectable').addClass('deSelectable');
});

$(".deselectable").click(function()
{
    alert("deselect "+$(this).prop("class"));
    //data
    $(this).removeClass('deSelectable').addClass('selectable');
});
```

This code is working fine when I click li element first time. When I click '.selectable' for first time I am getting "select selectable", and for second time I am getting "select deselectable" instead "deselect deselectable".

How do I alternate between the two methods when I click same 'li' element?

Comment: hey, instead of this .click function, you can you .toggleClass(), http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ which will hold good for your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` only binds to the elements matching the selector at the time of binding. You want to use `on` with delegated events:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectable', function() { ... });
$(document).on('click', '.deselectable', function() { ... });
```

Note that css classes are case sensitive. `deSelectable` is not `deselectable`.

If there is a container that will contain all selectable and unselectable, that will not be destroyed and is closer than `document`, use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in one event binding:

```
$(".selectable, .deselectable").click(function()
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selectable')) {
            alert("select "+$(this).prop("class"));
            //data
            $(this).removeClass('selectable').addClass('deselectable');
        } else {
            alert("deselect "+$(this).prop("class"));
            //data
            $(this).removeClass('deselectable').addClass('selectable');
        }
    }   
);
```

However if all you want to do is swap the classes then this will work even better:

```
$(".selectable, .deselectable").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selectable deselectable');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with one function, a toggle and no dependency on the markup.

```
var toggle = true;    
$(".selectable,.deselectable").click(function(){
    if(toggle){
       alert("option1");
    }else{
       alert("option2");
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
 });
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2qsKp/

Comment: The problem here is that the toggle is global so the toggle state is shared between elements (Click first Data, then second and you get option2 on the second even though it's the first click on it) which I don't think is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

did you check with .toggleClass() function http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/,

> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fMTsW/14/)

Just check this demo, may be this will help you.

```
$("li").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("selectable");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".selectable").click(function()
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selectable')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selectable').addClass('deselectable');
        } else
            $(this).removeClass('deselectable').addClass('selectable');
        }
    }   
);
$(".doselectable").click(function()
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selectable')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selectable').addClass('deselectable');
        } else
            $(this).removeClass('deselectable').addClass('selectable');
        }
    }   
);
```